# Find the closest pair of integers (a,b) that make a known product P

Tags: integers

**For any positive integer `P`, is there a formula or an algorithm that can find the closest pair `X` of integers `a` and `b`, that multiplied together result in that integer `P`?**

In other words: knowing `P`, find closest `a` and `b` that satisfy `a * b = P`

By *closest* I mean - the difference between `a` and `b` is smallest possible.

---

**Square example:** I have a number `256`. I know, using square root, that `a = 16` and `b = 16` will be that pair `X` I'm looking for. For `P` being a square of any integer this is easy. How about for other integers?

**Non-square example:** if `P = 198`, I found that `a = 11` and `b = 18` is my pair `X`. This time however I had to go through trial and error (picking random numbers) to find my answer.

- Is there any way I could calculate the pair `X` automatically?
- Is there a name for the problem I'm describing?
- Am I missing something (such as edge cases that can't be calculated)?

---

*Context (feel free to ignore this): I'm working with images. Sometimes, the data is provided in a flattened format (as one row of numbers), and I'm trying to figure out how to unravel the data back to the image format of width x height (however please don't worry about whether I guess the correct dimensions of the original data - it's irrelevant). Therefore, having a and b closest to each other is needed in my use case.*

Comment: I don't know if this comment will help you. Anyway, have you considered to use prime decomposition?. For example, $198=2\cdot 3 \cdot 3\cdot 11$. So your problem is reduced to find the best rearrangement: $(2\cdot 3\cdot 3)\cdot 11$.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting! I'm not sure I understand it completely, but I'll look into prime decomposition. However, isn't your suggestion assuming that I know `a=11`?

Comment: No... Well, What I have tried to explain was if you know prime factors of $P=p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot \cdots \cdot p_n$, you ''only'' have to evaluate $n \choose 2$ posibilities (more or less): $(p_1)\cdot(p_2\cdot\cdots \cdot p_n)$ or $(p_1\cdotp_2)\cdot(p_3\cdot \cdots\cdot p_n)$ or...  However, note I omiting possible powers $p_i^{a_i}$, which can make the problem more difficult (than I have assumed in this comment).

Comment: I don't know what does ''trial and error'' mean for you. How have you found $11$ and $18$? Picking random numbers, for example $12$ and $18$, $15 $ and $21$, etc and then demonstrating their product is $198$ and finding which is the closest pair?

Comment: Yes - "trial and error" means: picking random integers that multiplied result in 198.

Comment: You could develop an algorithm based on starting with $N$ equal to the integer part of $\sqrt P$,  then successively decrementing $N$ until $\frac PN$ is an integer

Comment: I'm afraid there is probably no efficient algorithm in the general case. That would imply the ability to factor large semiprimes.